# Complementary answers - How to decide what answer to accept?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty, accepted-answer

What to do when two answers to my question are complementary to each other. I have asked [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158585/magento-2-javascript-plugin-after-method-is-executed-in-wrong-time/159092#159092) and got two answers.

Should I Edit and accept answer that was more helpful to me, but was not complete. Doing it based on another answer that I got to my question (I think that it would be unethical to other user who answered that question) or what should I do?

To me it seems that the answer would be more useful to other members when it would be complete solution (both code and explanation). But the answer that i would like to accept is not complete in code part?

Answer (score 7):

### Which answer should accept ?

You should accept an answer which is more helpful to you. If other answers are equally good and you are not sure which answer should accept, then what I do in such case is, look at the timestamps of those answer and accept the very first answer in that race.

These are some suggestions and not rules. Listen to your mind and act accordingly.

### What should I do if answer is not complete ?

You can ask to the answerer whose answer you wanted to accept to edit his answer and put that "additional part", with that, you think the answer will be completed.

If he/she is not doing that, then you can answer your own question with that additional part and also put a hint about the good answer you thought initially to accept in your own answer. Then accept your answer. But you should do this only if the first suggestion is not worked out for you.

### If you still feel bad about other equally good answers

You can upvote that answer to show your respect and gratitude :)

If that didn't console you, then you can put a comment on the accepted answer that indicates there are other interesting answers to look into. This will eventually make other people notice about those equally good answers and there is higher chance to get upvote on those answers too.

These are suggestions. I wish you can take a good decision based on this.